# Is there something like go-eldoc-mode for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, go

eldoc-mode show you the parameters of the function you are calling when you write in Emacs Lisp.  Does anything like this exist for Google Go in Emacs?

Answer (score 3):

Look here: https://github.com/nsf/gocode and there at 'Emacs setup'.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [go-eldoc](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-go-eldoc). You can install go-eldoc with package.el from MELPA.